# Power Automate Approval blocks DoUntil timeout

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

In Power Automate, I've created a workflow with a do-until loop. When I set the timeout to 5mins it times-out and execution continues. I've added an approval task within the do-until loop and now the flow is waiting for the user to approve/reject. If I do not approve/reject I would expect the do-until loop to timeout in 5mins, but it doesn't repect the timeout set in the do until loop and continues waiting.

When will it timeout ?
If I want the approval task to be time limited what can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly set the time-out on the approval action and configure the action for time-out condition.
[image]

[image]

Tutorial which may be helpful:https://www.serverlessnotes.com/docs/power-automate-approval-timeouts-and-escalations